# The CLI of PhpStorm detects the PHP version in docker environment

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm

**Problem description**

I want to use in MAC environment Docker Xdebug configuration CLI mode, adjustment of the breakpoint, my container internal PHP version is mounted in the data volume, so every time need to start the container, mount data volume to get PHP 7.0, while the default image of internal version is PHP 7.3 version of PhpStorm don't know why is detected 7.3 rather than 7.0. How do I configure this?

Have studied for a day, also did not study come out, looked up official website also did not have a result, do not know somebody had had the same circumstance?

[image]

**The platform version of the problem and what you've tried**

- Mac 10.15.5 (19F101)
- PhpStorm 2020.1
- Docker 19.0.3.8
- PHP 7.0

I tried to configure the Docker inside PhpStorm and the service was deployed and available, but the CLI interpreter still didn't match the correct version of PHP.

**What are you looking for? What is the error message you actually see?**

Expect the CLI interpreter to match the correct version 7.0 of PHP with Xdebug, not 7.3 inside the container

Comment: If you are 100% sure that you do have PHP 7.0 in that container, login inside and use something like `which php` (or is it `where php`) to see the full path to the `php` executable. If it will show v7.0 -- use FULL PATH for "PHP executable" field instead of just `php`. If it will show v7.3, then double check your image / do a filesystem `find` command to locate other PHP installations.

Comment: My PHP7.0 is mounted on a data volume in the Container, and 7.3 in image. Therefore, I am not sure whether a container is run separately when CLI tests here, instead of testing from the existing container

Comment: Cannot really help here then: I'm not familiar with such setup and cannot say if it will work properly in PhpStorm. I suggest to post a question on PhpStorm forums or submit a ticket to their Support Team: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200367219-PhpStorm

Comment: Try to set a full path to your php 7.0, instead of just "php". I believe you have different paths to php7.0 and php7.3?